# php + angularjs: how send information in flashdata to a function in a angularjs controller

Tags: php, angularjs, codeigniter

I have some information in session flashdata. I need to validate if the information exist, then send it to a function in a angular controller

This is a example of my code:

```
<?php if (isset($this->session->flashdata('userUrl'))) ?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?= base_url(); ?>js/scripts/authorization.js"></script>
    {{loginUrl($this->session->flashdata('userUrl'), $this->session->flashdata('passUrl'))}}

<?php endif ?>
```

in the browser have this message

Fatal error: Cannot use isset() on the result of a function call (you can use "null !== func()" instead) in /usr/share/nginx/html/comercios/application/views/api_cms_controller/admin/admin.php on line 6

the line 6 is the isset line

Comment: what issues are you experiencing?

Comment: as you've updated, it literally tells you the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is described accurately by the php error. `isset` cannot be used directly around a function call.

Thus: `if (isset($this->session->flashdata('userUrl')))` has to become `if (null !== $this->session->flashdata('userUrl'))`

OR:

`if (isset($_SESSION['userUrl']))` and perhaps `if (isset($_SESSION['userUrl']) && !empty($_SESSION['userUrl']))`

OR (should work):

`if ($this->session->has_userdata('userUrl'))`

Comment: Honestly, I had tried that solution and it had not worked, now if it works, it's weird

I apologize if I abuse this same question but now I have this error, can you help me?

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'endif' (T_ENDIF) in /usr/share/nginx/html/comercios/application/views/api_cms_controller/admin/admin.php on line 10

Comment: I think `if (isset($this->session->flashdata('userUrl'))):` missing colon. and for good measure `endif` should be `endif;` (not required by cleaner).